# What Russian words other than "дрожжи" have a soft ж in common pronunciation?

Tags: произношение

Although it is sometimes taught that there is no soft ж in Russian, in fact this is not so and many Russians pronounce a soft ж in the word дрожжи.

What other Russian words contain a ж which is pronounced soft in standard or at least common pronunciation? And what are some good rules for remembering when a ж should be pronounced soft?

Comment: `Дожди` used to be pronounced `[Дожжьи]`, but it is no longer widespread either.

Comment: @alamar [citation needed]

Comment: @Wilson https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently palatalization of **`[ж]`** **MAY** occur in cases of its phonetic gemination **`[жж]`** due to assimilation of an adjacent phoneme of the word root. In all such cases this adjacent phoneme can alternate with **`[ж]`** in other roots as well.

Other such words are:

1) **`дожди`** (rains) - which can be pronounced **`[дажжи]`** due to assimilation of **`[д]`** able to alternate with **`[ж]`** in other roots as well: са**д** - са**ж**ать, си**д**еть - си**ж**у  etc.

2) **`подожди`** (wait!) - **`[падажжи]`** for reason as in 1)

3) **`позже`** (later) - **`[пожже]`** due to assimilation of **`[з]`** able to alternate with **`[ж]`** in other roots as well: ла**з**ить - ла**ж**у, во**з**ить - во**ж**у  etc.

4) **`вожжи`** (reins) - this is conventional spelling, which can also have the form of **`возжи`** because its root is essentially **`воз`** just like in the verb **`возить`** mentioned above, so the reason for gemination **`[жж]`** is as in 3)
4а) also sing. **`вожжа`** - which can be pronounced as **`[вожжя]`**

5) **`жжёт`** (burns) - this is conventional spelling, where the gemination **`[жж]`** occurs due to assimilation of the root phoneme **`[г]`** which features in such cognates as **`зажиГать`**, **`ожоГ`** and which is able to alternate with **`[ж]`** in other roots as well: бо**г** - бо**ж**иться, мо**г**у - мо**ж**ет, ло**г** - ло**ж**бина, ро**г** - ро**ж**ок, дру**г** - дру**ж**ить etc.

Now the gemination **`[жж]`** in **`дрожжи`**, which is conventional spelling like **`жжёт`**, can't be explained by reference to its root or other Russian words, because the word is unique. However it can be explained by reference to its [etymology](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B6%D0%B8) and equivalents in other Slavic languages

> Происходит от праслав. *drozga, от кот. в числе прочего произошли:
>   ст.-слав. дрождиѩ мн. (Син. Пс.), укр. дрíжджi, дрíщi, болг. дро́ждие,
>   сербохорв. дро̀жда ж., словенск. drôzga «отвар солода», чешск. droždí
>   «дрожжи», словацк. droždie мн., польск. drożdże, в.-луж. droždźe,
>   н.-луж. droždźeje.

Apparently it derives from the root **`дрожд`** or **`дрозг`**. Whatever the case, all **`д`**, **`з`** and **`г`** can (as shown above) assimilate into or alternate with **`ж`** to fashion gemination **`дроЖЖи`**.

---

**`Дажжи`** (дожди) и **`падажжи`** (подожди) are different from the rest in this list in that palatalized pronunciation of **`[жж]`** in them is the **only** option. Their penultimate phoneme **`[д]`** is palatalized in the normative pronunciation due to **`[и]`**, so after its assimilation into **`[ж]`** the palatalization is simply kept. 
The other words allow for alternative pronunciation, either with or without palatalization.

Comment: Thanks for this. Now I'm wondering whether there are any cases of geminated /ж/ *without* part of the prolonged sound having an association with another phoneme that can in other forms of the word alternate with /ж/.

Comment: @ruffle i don't think there're any

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because there is so much well-communicated information in it. But strictly I asked whether any words other than дрожжи are *commonly* pronounced with soft ж. If I had to guess I would say perhaps вожжи should go on the list, but I've never heard a soft ж in езжу, позже, or дожди even if reliable sources say it can be used in these words. Unfortunately I haven't got any native Russian speakers around at the moment whom I can ask!

Comment: @ruffle well since i'm a native speaker just like the rest of the contributors, you can ask me in particular, all words i've listed i heard pronounced with palatalized Ж, including езжу, which i overlooked, дожди and подожди i myself pronounce this way when i'm lazy to spell it out fully... i don't think though that any of these words are commonly pronounced this way, it's a matter of speaker's idiosyncrasy, дрожжи i personally prefer as дрожжы

Comment: It's accent related pronunciation. 

Russians from Moscow and related region usually say like Баян Купи-ка written. 

Russians from Saint Petersburg or North-West Russia don't use soft ж at all.

Answer (score 3):

The [Russian Wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%96#%D0%A1%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B8_%C2%AB%D0%BC%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%C2%BB_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0) lists the following words:

- до[ж’ж’]и (дожди)
- дро[ж’ж’]и (дрожжи)
- по[ж’ж’]е (позже)
- е[ж’ж’]у (езжу)
- ви[ж’ж’]ять (визжать)
- дребе[ж’ж’]ять (дребезжать)
- бре[ж’ж’]ить (брезжить)

We don't hear much of the soft Ж these days. You are more likely to hear a hard Ж in the words above and [жд] in **дожди**.

Answer (score 0):

The most common of such words that is also commonly mispronounced is дождь. Often even native speakers pronounce it with a soft д at the end which is not supposed to be. Here’s how it’s pronounced in a famous [song from 1990s](https://youtu.be/-uCTyC1FGLw?t=14), here’s a standard [pronunciation](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB:Ru-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%8C_(%C9%95).ogg)

A less common word is вожжи, a horse tack.